# Show that $\det(A^s) = (\det(A))^s$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, determinant

**Let A be an $n\times n$ matrix. Show that  $\det(A^s) = (\det(A))^s$ for every $s\in \mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$**

($\det$ is the determinant of the matrix).

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$?

Comment: @carmichael561 yes I am aware of this but I'm unsure of how you can use this in this question.

Comment: Do you know how to use induction?

Comment: Taking $B=A$, you get $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2$, for instance. In general, you can use induction.

Comment: So would you then do det(A²B) = det(A^3) = det(A)^3 and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Proceed by induction:
For $s=1$, it's trivial.  Assume true for $s=k$, prove for $s=k+1$.
Then

$\det{A^{k+1}}= \det{(A^k)} det A=(\det{A})^k\det{A}=(\det{A})^{k+1}$